# How to track an error in node.js traceback?

Tags: node.js

I'm very new to Node.js and right now I'm looking at the traceback after an error. The traceback starts with something promising:

```
buffer.js:140
    throw new TypeError('must start with number, buffer, array, or string')
```

The question is: how to find this `buffer.js` so I can start investigating?

Context and what I've done:

- It's a custom app and I started it with `babel-node index.js`. I have little knowledge about `babel` or other such machinery.
- I've searched the app's directory for `buffer.js`. I've found two files called `buffer.js`, but neither of them has this line 140 or anything resembling that.
- From what I see `babel-node` is installed in my `AppData/Roaming/npm`. It's installed “globally”; again, I'm not quite sure what it means, maybe that it's on `PATH`. I've searched that directory as well and found (the same) two `buffer.js` files, neither of which is relevant.
- My understanding is that this is a Node.js app, so I've searched the Node.js directory. Here I found two different `buffer.js` files from some `promzard`, but they're not what I'm after.

So how do I locate this file? Where else to look? Could it be that it's embedded into something and thus the name just a remnant?

Answer (score 0):

Print the exception stack trace this will help you and it will show the complete path how error produced and at which line and file generating the error.
Write the following line in your function where you are catching the exception.

```
console.log(ex.stack);
```